# typescript arrow functions as pointers variables in a tab

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I pass an arrow function as a variable in a tab ?

I have a function like this :

```
public handleLogin(data) {
  this.socket.send(data);
  [...]
}
```

which is in a functions tab :

```
let tab = [this.handleLogin];

tab[0](data);
```

But when I call handleLogin by the tab my socket attribute is undefined (seems like 'this' doesn't refers to my class instance but to the function instance so it would not be an arrow function).

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: Might be helpful to check [this part of wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#red-flags-for-this) as well.

Comment: There is no arrow function in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let tab = [(data) => { this.handleLogin(data); }];
tab[0](data);
```

The arrow function wrapper preserve `this` context during `handleLogin` execution.

Comment: this works perfectly thank you